# Why am I getting "Element type is invalid" error?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, debugging, react-native

In the `error` I'm getting in my `iOS` simulator doesn't make sense to me.  My `Home.js` component seems fine to me.  I can't understand how I'm getting this error.  I've clearly exported the component.  How can I get rid of this error?

Here's `Home.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'native-base';
import {MapContainer} from "../../../components/MapContainer/index";

class Home extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setName();
    }

    render() {
        const region = {
            latitude: 3.146642,
            longitude: 101.695845,
            latitudeDelta: 0.8922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
        }
        return(
            <Container>
                <MapContainer region={region}/>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Here's `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import View from 'native-base';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import styles from './MapContainerStyles';

export const MapContainer = ({region}) => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                region={region}
            >
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here's the `error`:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.  You 
likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of 'Home'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 exports in your `MapContainer`.

You have this one at the top `export const MapContainer`

and you have this one at the bottom. `export default MapContainer;`

Now you need to get rid of one, but the one you keep will determine how you import it later.

If you keep the default export you then import like so

`import MapContainer from "../../../components/MapContainer/index";`

If you keep the non default export you will import like so

`import {MapContainer} from "../../../components/MapContainer/index";`

Comment: ahhh I get it.  Thank you!

Comment: I get the concept completely.  But whenever I try to implement this in my code.  I still get the same error for some reason.

Comment: posted it now in my original post

Comment: Not sure. I just tried to recreate your scenario, and it worked fine for me. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

you have two exports here

```
import React from 'react';
import View from 'native-base';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import styles from './MapContainerStyles';

//delete export from the next line
export const MapContainer = ({region}) => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                region={region}
            >
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );

}

export default MapContainer;
```